# How to use Type in a dictionary

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Very simply, I have a dictionary:

```
public IDictionary<string, Type> abilities_parts = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
```

For some reason "Type" is not highlighting blue and getting recognized as a keyword. Googling this is a nightmare. Am I missing a reference or something?

Edit: The solution was that I wasn't using 'system', which Type requires.

Comment: That should compile as long as you have: `using System;` and `using System.Collections.Generic;`

Comment: Could just be an IDE highlighting issue rather than an actual build error? Does your code build?

Comment: The value in your dictionary could be int, long, string, byte, ....  There is nothing wrong with the statement that the compiler would detect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Type" requires using System; You might look at the your IDE too.